# Get the values from a nested JSON array in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5, reddit

So I have a piece of code that I have been fighting with for a while now.

Here is the code that I have

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Requests\SearchRequest;
use Vinelab\Http\Client as HttpClient;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SearchResults extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('results.search-results');
    }

    public function store(Requests\SearchRequest $request)
    {

        $searchPhrase = $request->input('search');

        $client = new HttpClient;

        $response = $client->get('https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q='. urldecode($searchPhrase) .'');

        $response = collect($response->json());

        $responseDecode = json_decode($response, true);

        $SearchResultsArray = $responseDecode;

        dd($SearchResultsArray);
    }
}
```

And this returns a nested array that looks like this

```
 array:2 [▼
  "kind" => "Listing"
  "data" => array:5 [▼
    "facets" => []
    "modhash" => ""
    "children" => array:25 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "kind" => "t3"
        "data" => array:52 [▶]
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▶]
      2 => array:2 [▶]
      3 => array:2 [▶]
      4 => array:2 [▶]
      5 => array:2 [▶]
      6 => array:2 [▶]

    ]
    "after" => "t3_38lgh9"
    "before" => null
  ]
]
```

I am trying to access the title attribute that is inside each of these

```
  1 => array:2 [▶]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
  4 => array:2 [▶]
  5 => array:2 [▶]
  6 => array:2 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶]
```

I want to parse them to an array that I can send to a Laravel View.

Every time I try to acccess this I get undefined index or offset and I am at a loss as to how to go about this. 
Can anybody assist me in finding a solution to this problem?

Edit ---------------------

I am now using this and it is working perfectly

```
$allData=[];

        $counter = 1; 
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            //foreach post get the data and store it in a database
            $allData[$counter]['title']= $post['data']['title'];
            $sentiment = SentimentAnalysis::decision($allData[$counter]['title']);
            $allData[$counter]['created']= $post['data']['created'];

            RedditPosts::create([
                    'title' => $allData[$counter]['title'], 
                    'created' => date($allData[$counter]['created']),
                    'sentiment' => $sentiment,
                    'search_identifier' => $search_id,
                    'search_phrase' => $searchPhrase
                    ]);

            $counter ++;
        }
```

Comment: You basically need 3 foreach to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$allData=[];

    $counter = 1; 
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        //foreach post get the data and store it in a database
        $allData[$counter]['title']= $post['data']['title'];
        $sentiment = SentimentAnalysis::decision($allData[$counter]['title']);
        $allData[$counter]['created']= $post['data']['created'];

        RedditPosts::create([
                'title' => $allData[$counter]['title'], 
                'created' => date($allData[$counter]['created']),
                'sentiment' => $sentiment,
                'search_identifier' => $search_id,
                'search_phrase' => $searchPhrase
                ]);

        $counter ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would need three foreach in your case to achieve the nested arrays like this

```
foreach($SearchResultsArray as $ThreeLevelArray){

foreach($ThreeLevelArray as $TwoLevelArray) {

foreach($TwoLevelArray as $OneevelArray) {

//your here son :)

}
}

}
```

Comment: Once I get to //your here son :) how do I access the 'title' in the array? would it bet $OneevelArray->title;

Comment: you just reached 0 => array() 1 => array() 2=>array() so you want to get inside of that array too?

Comment: Yes, inside each of these 1 => array:2 [▶]
  2 => array:2 [▶]
  3 => array:2 [▶]
  4 => array:2 [▶]
  5 => array:2 [▶]
  6 => array:2 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶] there is data that I need

Comment: again one loop then :) so if you want key then you can use  foreach($OneLevelArray as $key => $value) { echo $key die();} check if it work

Comment: and then $OneevelArray->title?, let me try this quick

Comment: yes ! but again array inside array woh ! infinite loop?

Comment: Is there a better way to get this data?

Comment: I dont think there a way to get all array data without looping :)

Comment: So this is not the solution, thank you for the assistance though

Comment: Not solution lol you cant get all array data without looping you need to loop sir

Comment: haha I mean, I tried it and still not right, looking at another approach

Comment: you got what you need?

Comment: No not yet, the way that the json comes through from this is ridiculous

Comment: well its upto you , you can manipulate the data the way you want :)

Comment: I am looking at a possible new method of retrieving the data :)

Comment: Hey, I got it after a long day, have a look at the edited code in the question